# There is any way in javascript to access a element dynamicaly in array (eg: array.string)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is any way to access using index + string to this array?, knowing that there is n options, using for doing something like this?

```
var myArray = {input-name: 'xxx', option1: 20, option2: 50, option3: 40...option10:100};
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
  console.log(myArray.option+i);
 }
```

Comment: why not take an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/)?

Comment: `myArray`is not actually an array, but a JS object

Comment: `myArray['option'+i]`.

Comment: First, that is not an array. But, to answer you question the syntax is `myArray['option'+i]`

Comment: Why did you named your Object `myArray` and not `smoothing_iron` or `Apple_pie` ?

Comment: On the submit form i got all the inputs in a JS object, but i just want to collect the "options"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, just index the array with the key like this:

```
var myArray = {
    inputName: "xxx",
    option1: 20,
    option2: 50,
    option3: 40,
    option4: 30,
    option5: 100
}
    
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(myArray["option" + i])
}
```